# Unable to download and upload files from hdfs in namenode ui

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am getting the following error while uploading a file in user interface of http://awsip:50070/explorer.html#

Error:
Couldn't upload the file abc.zip.

core-site.xml :

```
 <configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020</value>
    <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
    scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
    uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
    the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
    determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.
    </description>
  </property>
 </configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml :

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
 </property>

 <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp/datanode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
     <value>0.0.0.0:8020</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-bind-host</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there any other error in a log file somewhere you can look at?

Comment: Hadoop hosted in aws and i am uploading the file from UI, I haven`t seen any logs generated for upload but while downloading it is taking private ip if i could change the public ip in URL I am able to download it, Do we have any other possibilities that i can directly download without changing the IP ?

Comment: Your hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml should be using FQDN of the machines, unless you are using static IPs in EC2

Comment: If your servers are in AWS, I don't understand how a localhost address is returning you that page

Comment: Additionally, why can't you just upload to S3? Or are you using HDFS in AWS?

Comment: ActuaIly its aws ip, I am able to upload the file  using following command :  hdfs fs -copyFromLocal /localpath /hdfspath but error occurring only when I do it from UI

Comment: I have added hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160779/discussion-between-praveen-mandadi-and-cricket-007).

Comment: 1) `fs.default.name` is a deprecated property. Should be `fs.defaultFS` 2) That must point at a namenode, not `hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020`, and should closely match `dfs.namenode.rpc-address`